# Javascript - Regexp - Global search Issue

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, output

I have got little issue.
I have got this:

```
var result1=content.match("/<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"']([^>\"']*)[\"'][^>]*>/gi")[1];
```

This code gives nothing. I'm sure that input and Regex are right, but:

1. It gives me an error :  Cannot read property `1` of `null`.
2. When I remove `[1]` then `result1 = null` and also it's not array.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please show what's in `content` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pass regex as a string:

```
content.match("/<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"']([^>\"']*)[\"'][^>]*>/gi")[1];
```

should be

```
content.match(/<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"']([^>\"']*)[\"'][^>]*>/gi)[1];
```

Example:

```
> a = "abc"
"abc"
> a.match("/abc/")
null
> a.match(/abc/)
["abc"]
```

Following m.buettner's comment. If you need to build a regex from string use this syntax:

```
var my_regex = new RegExp("abc", "gi");
```

Comment: alternatively, if the OP does need a string (because he's building it dynamically), `content.match(new RegExp(string, 'gi'))[1];`

Answer (score 2):

Remove quotes around regexp or use `new RegExp` constructor. It should be:

```
var result1 = content.match(/<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"']([^>\"']*)[\"'][^>]*>/gi);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGWEt/1/

Using RegExp constructor:

```
var result1 = content.match(RegExp("<a [^>]*href\s*=\s*[\"']([^>\"']*)[\"'][^>]*>", "gi"));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wGWEt/2/